# Gradle: how to configure buildSrc or skip tests from main project?

Tags: groovy, junit, gradle, build.gradle

I have some fairly long tests in my buildSrc build which I sometimes want to skip during development, to see the effect that template changes have. It's a report generator and sometimes I just want to tweak the templates without having to update all the tests; then later I will update them when I'm happy with the output.

I was able to implement skipping tests within the buildSrc build.gradle with the following configuration:

```
test {
    // skip all tests if gradle run with -Pnotests
    try { if (project.ext.notests != null)
        println "skipping tests"
        exclude '**'
    } catch (MissingPropertyException e) {}
}
```

(and if you have a better way to detect an optional parameter I'd love to see it)

However, this doesn't work from the main gradle project. I have tried everything I can think of to try to pass the parameter through configuration, short of setting an environment variable, but I doubt that would work either.

In general I find I can't configure buildSrc whatsoever from the main project. I can't  find any way to get at variables, eg project.ext.foo or ext.foo, nor a way to configure the buildSrc 'project' as there is no section in main build.gradle. It's like it exists on an island of its own. I've tried:

- project.ext.notests = true
- test {...} in main
- allprojects { test {...} }
- subprojects { test {...} }
- dependencies { test {...} }
- buildscript { test {...} }

Is there a way around this, or do I have to refactor my whole project to move the reporting code elsewhere and maybe then I can configure it and skip tests?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`buildSrc` is a separate *build* (not project), and I'm not aware of a way to influence its execution when triggering the main build. (Note that building `buildSrc` is a prerequisite for evaluating the main build's build scripts.) Some solutions I can think of:

- Unconditionally disable `buildSrc` tests for as long as required (e.g. by setting `test.disabled = true` in `buildSrc/build.gradle`)
- Factor out `buildSrc` into a separate build
- Change tests so that they are insensitive to template changes
- Move tests that are sensitive to template changes into a separate `Test` task that's only triggered manually

PS: The easiest way to skip a build's tests from the command line is `-x test`. The existence of a project property `foo` can be detected with `project.hasProperty("foo")`.

Comment: Thanks Peter. My intermediate solution was your first solution, but I wanted more flexibility on build servers too.

Comment: I suspected your 2nd solution would be the best - and this might help with other areas too like making my reporting a deployable artifact. Then use the solution I saw in the Spock project to use the classes in the build script, without running tests. 

I had also tried -x test from the main project but this didn't cascade to buildSrc. I assume it will apply to projects though.

Comment: Would there be any way to *optionally* use a versioned maven artifact in the build script, *or* the current source? As far as I can tell this is dependency loop, ie build builds artifact, but script needs artifact to be up to date to run build...

Comment: I didn't mean to say that `-x test` cascades to `buildSrc` (nothing does). I'm not aware of a way to get Gradle do disregard `buildSrc` even though it's there.

Comment: Looks like there is no `test.disabled` property. For first option above, use `test.enabled = false`.

Comment: Thank you, this is basic but important info that is not clearly specified elsewhere

Answer (score 3):

I tried your idea of an environment variable and it does, in fact, work:

```gradle
def skipTests = Boolean.parseBoolean(System.env['BUILDSRC_SKIP_TESTS'])

test {
  enabled = !skipTests
  // ... other settings here ...
}
```

(tested this in Gradle 4.9.)

One might also use such a variable to disable other checks, e.g.:

```gradle
tasks.findAll { it.name.startsWith('findbugs') || it.name.startsWith('checkstyle') }
  .each { it.enabled = !skipTests }
```

Comment: Good work :) It might be supported in more recent versions of Gradle, but since posting this, I've moved on quite a bit. Thanks for your answer for others though.